# Passing a bash command-line argument containing a dot

Tags: bash, command-line, shell-script, escape-characters

How can a command-line argument containing a dot (.) be passed? Are there any escape sequences for capturing characters like dot?

The following invocation of a bash-script from the shell does not work:

```
# ./deploy.sh input.txt
./deploy.sh: line 9: input.txt: syntax error in expression (error token is ".txt")
```

I have tried the following:

1. backslash
2. quote
3. double quotes
4. ./deploy.sh input (this works)

**EDIT**

Take this use-case:

1. I have 3 files: server.jar client.jar gui.jar
2. I need to scp them from a source to a dest
3. source dir: login1@host1:/home/xyz/deploy/
4. dest dir: login2@host2: /data/apps/env/software/binary/

Solution:

1. Read artifacts to be copied into an array from the command-line
2. create dest path and source path strings by using the correct directory prefixes
3. use a for loop to scp each artifact (having figured out the paths)

Here's the simple script which is doing 1 (read artifacts into an array):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a artifacts
for i
do
artifacts[i]=$i
echo ${artifacts[i]}
done
```

*Execution1*

```
-bash-3.00$ ./simple.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

*Execution2*

```
-bash-3.00$ ./simple.sh arg1.txt arg2.txt arg3.txt
./simple.sh: line 7: arg1.txt: syntax error in expression (error token is ".txt")
```

Comment: There is nothing special about dots in `bash`; this sounds like an issue with your script `deploy.sh` and we would need to see it to know what it's doing and how (if at all) to change it.

Comment: You should show us deploy.sh.

Comment: @cjc @geekosaur Thanks for your comments, I tried a simple hello-world sort of script and it does accept arguments with a dot (.). I'll try moving the commands from my `deploy.sh` script to my hello-world script to see what's going wrong and repost.

Comment: What is line 9? :-)

Comment: Probably an error somewhere in between `$(( ... ))` or in a `let` statement.

Comment: Here's my simple script from my original script:

`#!/bin/bash

declare -a artifacts

for i
do
    artifacts[i]=$i
    echo ${artifacts[i]}
done`


**Execution1**
`-bash-3.00$ ./simple.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
arg1
arg2
arg3`

*Execution2*
-bash-3.00$ ./simple.sh arg1.txt arg2.txt arg3.txt
./simple.sh: line 7: arg1.txt: syntax error in expression (error token is ".txt")

Comment: Woah!  Put your code in the question.  Makes reading it much easier.

Comment: Okay, the code is in the question now! New to stackexchange :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3403/discussion-between-maelstrom3-and-mikel)

Comment: We don't need to continue in chat.  You just need you to put enough information in the question so we can reproduce your problem.  Which you have now done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `declare -A` instead of `declare -a`.  You are clearly using associative arrays with arbitrary string arguments as indices, but `declare -a` is only for integer indexed arrays.  `arg.txt` does not evaluate to a valid integer, hence your error.

#### Edit

You seem to be using `bash` version 3.  Unfortunately, associative arrays are not available until version 4.  I recommend you post a sanitized version of your original `deploy.sh` script with sensitive personal information removed so you can get ideas from other people about alternative approaches.

#### Edit 2

Just to summarize a bit of exchange in the chat:

The easiest way to do some action over all the arguments is to just iterate over them with a `for` loop:

```
    for arg; do
        scp login1@host1:"$arg" login2@host2:/dest/
    done
```

Remember to double-quote all instances of `"$arg"`.
You do *not* need to put the arguments in an array yourself, as they already exist in the array `$@`, which is what `for` uses by default when you don't give an explicit `in list...`.

Answer (score 5):

That error happens any time you try to use a string where a number was expected.

For example

```
$((input.txt))
```

will cause the same error to be printed.

In your case, it turns out you were assigning to an array which uses a numeric index.

jw013 rightly [explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38425/3169) you need to do `declare -A` (uppercase A) for your example to work.

The reason why:

When assigning to an array element, you would normally write

```
array[0]=foo
array[1]=bar
```

but you can also write any [arithmetic expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) as the key, e.g.

```
array[0+0]=foo
array[1+0]=bar
```

so the shell is seeing

```
array[input.txt]=input.txt
```

trying to convert it to a number like

```
$((input.txt))
```

and failing.

The reason the dot is confusing and that arguments without a dot seem to work is that

```
$((input))
```

is actually a valid number.

`bash` sees `input`, decides it's a valid variable name, sees that the variable is unset, and replaces it with `0`.

Compare that to `input.txt`, which is not a valid variable name, because variable names can't contain dots!

To avoid this confusing behavior, you can use

```
set -u
```

then any time you try to use a variable that doesn't exist, you'll get an error, e.g.

```
set -u
artifacts[arg1]=arg1
```

prints the error

```
scriptname: line number: arg1: unbound variable
```